How to Optimize Atomic Positions and Volume While Preserving Cell Shape in VASP?
I’m working on optimizing a crystal structure using VASP 6.3.2, and I need a method to optimize both atomic positions and cell volume while keeping the cell shape fixed, in order to preserve the initial symmetry of the structure.
ISIF=7 adjusts the volume while keeping the cell shape fixed, but it does not optimize the atomic positions, which leads to residual stress in the structure. ISIF=2, on the other hand, optimizes the atomic positions but keeps the volume fixed, which is not ideal for relieving stress in a structure where volume relaxation is necessary.
Since ISIF=8, which could potentially handle this scenario, is not available in my version of VASP, I’m looking for ideas or workflows to achieve this goal in VASP 6.3.2. Are there any alternative strategies or external tools that can help in this case? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

In my case, I use ISIF=3 at first, then ISIF=2.
Because my starting poscar comes from an already optimized cif file.
But if you are generating a poscar file, I recommend using ISIF=7 at first.
Then use IFIS=3 and 2!
If the structure is not optimized even after completing ISIF=2, repeat ISIF=3 and 2 enough times.
good luck!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you very much for your insights! I have a question regarding the use of ISIF=3. Since ISIF=3 allows for changes in the cell shape, isn't it expected that the crystal system might change as a result? In my case, when I perform ISIF=3 optimizations after elemental substitutions in the structure taken from the Materials Project database, I noticed that the crystal system changes. Do you think ISIF=3 is still a reasonable approach in this case?
